# Task.Run is bad to use on a job scheduler service

Tags: c#, .net, job-scheduling

I have a job scheduler (windows service) which runs every few mins and tries to do async jobs for long running tasks. And I do see CPU usage is high when multiple jobs are running. Do I need to avoid using Task.Run and approach it in a different way?

```
 public void Run()
    {
        var queueManager = new QueueManager();
        foreach (var taskId in queueManager.GetTaskIdsToProcess())
        {
            Task.Run(async () => InvokeProcess(taskId));
        }            
    }

    private void InvokeProcess(long taskId)
    {
        try
        {
            //Long Running process code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //update queue failed
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a complicated decision, and will require an understanding of your specific situation. How quickly do you need these tasks to finish processing from the time they're invoked? Is the CPU being shared with other important services, so by using more CPU you end up impacting other critical systems? How much time do the tasks typically spend waiting (async) on other systems? Are many of the tasks making demands on the same resources? If so, how well do those resources handle many concurrent requests suddenly? And so on.

Comment: `//Long Running process code` what does it do? That's what you need to look at. `Task.Run` doesn't do anything magical, it just hands off to a threadpool thread, so if you're looping heavily it's still going to burn CPU

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Task may take 15 mins to process and some tasks may complete in 30 secs. And yes CPU is shared with API and I see slowness on API side too. Can i rewrite something like async wait instead of Task.Run?

Comment: No that won't help. If you burn CPU you can't speed it up by putting it in a task or whatever. You need to analyze your algorithm and see why it's taking so long.

Comment: Well, if you're looping heavily on a single thread, that'll only impact one CPU core at a time, and have a minimal effect on other apps running on the same machine, so you could just run InvokeProcess synchronously in your loop. But if you run all these tasks in serial it will take longer for them all to complete. If that's not acceptable, you'll probably need to find a middle ground where you limit how many items you process at a time (e.g. Guru Stron's answer). Or figure out whether there's something you can do to make each task more efficient (algorithm improvements, caching, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that it is not `Task.Run` per se, but either the `InvokeProcess` is CPU-intensive or you code can result in quite high number of task scheduled simultaneously on the thread pool which can in turn schedule up to `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out var workerThreads, out var _)` threads, hence high CPU load, or both.

Usual approach is to have some kind of concurrent queue and limited number of `Task`'s/`Thread`'s processing it. For example a simple one can look like:

```cs
class Processor
{
    private readonly CancellationToken _stoppingToken;
    private DefaultBackgroundTaskQueue Queue = new(1000);
    private Task[] _Processors;

    public Processor(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _stoppingToken = stoppingToken;
        var instances = 8;
        _Processors = Enumerable.Range(0, instances)
            .Select(_ => Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    var taskId = Queue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);
                    try
                    {
                        // process taskId - InvokeProcess(taskId)
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e); // log
                    }

                }
            }))
            .ToArray();
    }
    public async Task Run()
    {
        var queueManager = new QueueManager();
        foreach (var taskId in queueManager.GetTaskIdsToProcess())
        {
            await Queue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(taskId);
        }            
    }

    private void InvokeProcess(long taskId)
    {
        try
        {
            //Long Running process code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //update queue failed
        }
    }
}

public sealed class DefaultBackgroundTaskQueue 
{
    private readonly Channel<long> _queue;

    public DefaultBackgroundTaskQueue(int capacity)
    {
        BoundedChannelOptions options = new(capacity)
        {
            FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait
        };
        _queue = Channel.CreateBounded<long>(options);
    }

    public async ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(long workItem)
    {
        await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(workItem);
    }

    public async ValueTask<long> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var workItem = await _queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);

        return workItem;
    }
}
```

Also check out:

- [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)
- [Create a Queue Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/queue-service)
- Also you can consider something like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to manage sheduling.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to avoid using `Task.Run` and approach it in a different way?

No, the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) is fine. The reason for the CPU spikes is that the work that you assign to the `Task.Run` is CPU-bound, at least partially. The overhead of using the `Task.Run` per se is minuscule. You can start a million `Task.Run`s per second, and the CPU will not even notice (assuming that the work of each `Task.Run` is zero). If you want to reduce the CPU utilization, you have basically two options:

1. Reduce the number of the tasks that are running concurrently at any given moment.
2. Optimize the work performed by each task.

Neither option is trivial. The extend to which you can optimize either the scheduling or the algorithms depends on your familiarity and expertise with the Task Parallel Library, and the .NET APIs and data structures in general.