# Types of asynchronous background code execution in REST API endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am implementing a REST API endpoint in ASP.NET, that should do the following:

1. Asynchronously start a long-running algorithm
2. Return 202 Accepted immediately after starting the algorithm (no await)

This is what the endpoint looks like:

```cs
app.MapPut(
    "/api/instance/{id}",
    (int id, InstanceDto instanceDto, IInstanceRunningService service) =>
    {
        // Start the execution asynchronously and return ASAP
        service.RunInstance(instanceDto);
        return TypedResults.Accepted($"/api/instance/{id}");
    })
```

This is what the `RunInstance` method in the service looks like:

```cs
public async Task RunInstance(InstanceDto instanceDto)
{
    // Asynchronously call another API that we are starting the execution of the algorithm
    // We do not need to wait for the response, we just want to start the algorithm ASAP (again no await)
    _ = this.AnotherApiClient.PutAsync(instanceDto);

    // Compute the algorithm and await the result
    var result = await Algorithm.Run(instanceDto.Parameters);
    
    // Finally call the other API again to notify that the computation finished
    await this.AnotherApiClient.PutAsync(instanceDto);
}
```

The order of operations I want to achieve is:

1. Return 202 Accepted
2. Notify another API that computation is starting (we don't care how this API call ends, because we will be sending another one in step 4.)
3. Compute the algorithm
4. Notify another API that computation has finished

I can't figure out the best way to achieve this. There are so many options:

- `service.RunInstance(instanceDto);`
- `service.RunInstance(instanceDto).Start();`
- `Task.Run(() => service.RunInstance(instanceDto))`
- Make RunInstance an asynchronous delegate and do `delegate.BeginInvoke()`
- Create a `Thread` or use `ThreadPool`
- Maybe implement the service differently with more async methods

Comment: Enqueue the requested computation in a queue that is processed by dedicated workers. I wouldn't recommend creating a new Thread for each request or using the pool. That could end up in disaster pretty quickly.

Comment: Why is the *long-running algorithm* taking a long time?  Is it waiting for responses from some server, reading and writing large files, or performing time consuming calculations?

Comment: @dbc By long-running I mean it is expected to be between 5-15 minutes. It's processing data and communicating with a database.

Comment: @Fildor Where would you store this queue in an ASP.NET application?

Comment: Depends. If we are talking "Azure" for example, you'd probably send it to a ServiceBus or EventHub or something similar, so you are pretty free in how you implement the workers. Respective components for other clouds ... if you are "on-prem" it depends if everything needs to be in-process or not.

Comment: Possibly related: [What is the simplest way to run a single background task from a controller in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222712/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-run-a-single-background-task-from-a-controller-in-n) and also [Run a background task from a controller action in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813628/run-a-background-task-from-a-controller-action-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: This article by Stephen Cleary might also be useful: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't figure out the best way to achieve this. There are so many options:

I would argue that none of them is "the best". The common approach for such task is to use some kind of background processing. The "simple" one is to just use the build-in one with [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio), especially check out the [Queued background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) option (you can instantiate several "processors" to handle the same queue - for example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76096715/2501279)).

Also do not pass the resolved dependencies (i.e. `IInstanceRunningService service`) to you handler task/queue since their lifetime is controlled by the lifetime of the original request and disposable services will be disposed with it, create scope manually and resolve everything needed from it - see the [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) section of the docs for example.

Alternatively you can look into using more advanced schedulers like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) and/or leveraging asynchronous processing with queue/service bus.

Comment: Thank you that is actually super useful, because a sort of scheduler is what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: About the service dependecy, now that I think of it, it's even weird that my code actually worked, since the service is scoped and the scope should have ended way before I stopped using the service.

Comment: @Zdeněk finishing scope does not "destroy" "ordinary" services, so if you don't consume scoped/transient services or consumed services are not disposable then highly likely everything will work (though there can be some edge cases).